# Trendingview Stock Screener with financial data

Tags: pine-script

is there  a way to filter trandingview-stock screener with pine editor's financial data.

(i.e. Filtering stocks according to "RESEARCH_AND_DEVELOP_TO_REVENUE" in stock screener.)

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `RESEARCH_AND_DEVELOP_TO_REVENUE` is available in the function [financial()](https://tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_financial), but only the following metrics are available in the screener

[image]